# Error: <text>:1:1: unexpected input in R

Tags: r, shiny

I've got this error when called `htmlTemplate` in Shiny application on Windows 7:

```
Error: <text>:1:1: unexpected input
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was windows line ending, replacing it with Unix (LF) ending solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing line endings to Unix (LF), I had to also remove blank lines from all the `.html` files that I called using `htmlTemplate`.